Invalid Template Error When using AWS::Include
I am getting an error saying "Transform AWS::Include failed with: The specified S3 object's content should be valid Yaml/JSON" when I am trying to deploy.
Below is my template.yaml file wherein I am using AWS::Include to split out few resources into a separate yaml file:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
    ....
Conditions:
    ....
Description:
    ....
Resources:
    DomainBasePathMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Condition: EnableDa
    Properties: 
      BasePath: "account"
      DomainName: !Ref apiDomainName
      RestApiId: !Ref LoanAccountApi
      Stage: !Ref LoanAccountApiStage
    Fn::Transform:
    Name: AWS::Include
    Parameters:
      Location: !Ref UsgPlanReminderResS3Location
Outputs:
    ....

and below is the partial yaml file having rest of the resources--
Resources:
  UsagePlanReminderTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic

  UsagePlanReminderSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties: 
      Protocol: email
      Endpoint: !Ref SupportEmailAddress
      TopicArn: !Ref UsagePlanReminderTopic
   ..... 

When I tried to create a template by pasting the master template into CloudFormation-->Infrastructure Composer, I see the below errors of property and type missing.

I am not adding it as a resource but a link to other resources in the partial template file. Am I missing something here?

Try adding indentation to Name: AWS::Include and the subsequent lines. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html)

Indentation looks ok to me. As per error, looks like it is talking about the partial template and not the main one. So there is something wrong in the 2nd template, the partial one I guess.

Try removing word Resources: on the first line of in the include file. It seems that it is inserted in the main file as a resource.

I figured out that the issue is due to Unresolved tag !Ref in the include file. The parameters included with !Ref are present in main file so it is not considering it. Any idea what to do in that case?

I also tried passing all required parameters from the "main" to "include" file but still the same error
